# React Native-- node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

Whenever I try to run **npm install** on the code cloned from repo. I get these errors :(
Can anyone help me to fix this problem :)

[image]

Comment: If the project is a public repository, then do add the link. So, that i could test !

Comment: Nope, I can't :(